# How to get another user's feed using Yammer's REST API?

Tags: yammer

Using the Yammer REST API, I can get the current logged-in user feed but would like to get the feed of other users. There doesn't seem to be an API for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This endpoint is documented on the supported API page for developers to use but this will work. https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/from_user/{{user_id}}.json

Be wary using undocumented apis in your own apps as they could change without warning from Yammer.

https://developer.yammer.com/docs/rest-api-rate-limits

Comment: thanks but I'd rather make use of the official documented API :)

Comment: I will accept the answer as I think this is the only way, unfortunately no public/documented API to do this so far...